# How to make a tag Mandatory or optional based on value of another tag in XSD1.0

Tags: xml, xsd, switch-statement, assert

I have the following XSD currently.

```
 <xsd:element name="ProcessingCode" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
              <xsd:enumeration value="000000" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="CardExpirationDate" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
              <xsd:pattern value="\d{4}" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
```

Now, I need to make CardExpirationDate as Mandatory only when the ProcessingCode value is 999999, else leave it optional. Kindly advise.

Answer (score 1):

Assertions are an XSD 1.1 mechanism, so the [original] title of your post which talks about using assertions in XSD 1.0 doesn't make much sense.

If you want to do such an assertion in XSD 1.1, then the assertion goes on the element that is the common ancestor of ProcessingCode and CardExpirationDate. If we assume that these are sibling elements then the common parent element would have an an assertion such as

```
<xs:assert test="ProcessingCode != '999999' or exists(CardExpirationDate)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. Is there any way to check for Processing code's value to make cardexpiration as Mandatory or optional in XSD 1.0? The processingcode tag's value will drive whether card expiration tag needs to be mandatory or optional.

Comment: No, XSD 1.0 does not provide any way to do this.